# Dropdown with custom input in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to have a dropdown field but being able to add a value other than the ones suggested by the dropdown?

Something like the [autocomplete](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) field with showAllItems set to true and without the auto-complete functionality

**Edit:**

What I want to achieve is just submit the form with the custom value or the user selection from the dropdown (according to the user's choice)

Comment: You want to make the user capable of adding a new item to the dropdown list or just make possible submitting the form with custom input (not from the list)?

Comment: Thank you for your notice jalooc I have edited my question, I only want to accept a custom input from the user and submit it with my form, thanks

Comment: an autocomplete component is not a substitute to a dropdown, for example it requires you to type at least one character prior to opening whereas with dropdown you can press the arrow-down icon. had you forced the autocomplete to open all items on focus, this wouldn't be a nice user experience. What you are looking for is a true combo-box.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `onNewRequest` attribute.
According to https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/auto-complete.jsx:

```
const AutoComplete = React.createClass({

...

render() {

...

return (
  <div style={mergedRootStyles} onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown}>
    <div style={{width: '100%',}}>
      <TextField
        {...other}
        ref="searchTextField"
        value={this.state.searchText}
        onEnterKeyDown={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this._close();
          }, this.props.touchTapCloseDelay);
          this.props.onNewRequest(this.state.searchText);
        }}

...
```

the function passed with this attribute is called everytime the user presses `Enter`, so you can just handle submitting the input inside of that function.

Comment: `onEnterKeyDown` has been deprecated and you can use `onKeyDown` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with mui autocomplete. Try using the `freeSolo` option

https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo